# display a video in html5 canvas and drag and drop

Tags: html, video, canvas, drag-and-drop

i'm already can upload mutiple images to canvas and drag and drop the images.
now i need to drag and drop the video that the users upload.
note the users can be able of have images and video at same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first load the video (wait its readyState to be 4).

Then you can, as frequently as you want, draw its content on your canvas as if it was any image :

```
function drawMyCanvas() {
    ...

    if (videoElement.readyState==4) {
            context.drawImage(videoElement, destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight);
            if (!videoElement.paused) {
                // set timeout for a new drawing 20 ms later
                window.setTimeout(drawMyCanvas, 20);
            }

  ...
```

When I do that I usually have a loop to draw the image every 20 ms and an handler on mousemove which calls my canvas drawing function if one of the movable objects moved.

Comment: thanks, thats works, but i have a problem, because i have.
c.fillStyle = "white";
c.fillRect(0, 0,1300, 768);
thats is to clear the canvas when im dragging an image.
the video is always blink in white..

Comment: If you draw the video frame in the same function than you do the fillRect, you shouldn't have flickering (I don't). Are you sure you draw the video each time you draw your canvas ?

Comment: var loop = setInterval(function() {
    
    c.fillStyle = "white";
    c.fillRect(0, 0,1300, 768);
   


    for(var img in images)
    {    
 images[img].update();               
    }
    
}, 10);

in .uptade()is where im drawing the images and where i draw the video frame